# How can I set up an Apple TV (4th gen) connection to a PPTP/L2TP VPN?

Tags: network, appletv, vpn

I have in the offices an Apple TV with a custom app that allows each office to see a dashboard with data.

The problem is that this data is in the main server, in the office headquarters. Is there any way I can setup a PPTP/L2TP VPN connection (something always on) in the Apple TV so that the app could gather the data from the main server?

PS. Opening the data in a public link or changing the app is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a router or Mac to connect to the VPN and then share that connection with the Apple TV.

Below is **one example** of how you could do this using a Mac. This should also give you the basic idea if you need to do something similar with a Windows machine or router<sup>1</sup>.

**Share VPN from a Mac**

1. Connect your Mac to the internet via ethernet cable (i.e. connect it to a router, modem, etc via ethernet)
2. Set up your VPN connection in System Preferences > Network (obviously you'll need the address and authentication details to do this)
3. Click on the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button
4. Ensure you tick the *Send all traffic over VPN connection* checkbox
5. You will also want to make sure that the two *Disconnect* options are not enabled
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
7. Ensure you also tick the checkbox for *Show VPN status in menu bar*
8. Now go to System Preferences > Sharing
9. Highlight (but do not tick) the Internet Sharing service in the lefthand pane
10. On the righthand side, select the VPN connection you created at Step 2 from the *Share your connection from* drop-down menu
11. Now select the Wi-Fi port (i.e. tick the checkbox)
12. Click on the <kbd>Wi-Fi Options...</kbd> button
13. Give your new Wi-Fi network a name, password etc
14. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
15. Now tick the Internet Sharing service in the lefthand pane

<sup>1</sup> It's impossible to give you precise steps as routers vary significantly. However you would need to ensure your router is capable of doing this and will need to refer to its user guide.

**NOTES:**

- You can also share a Wi-Fi connection via ethernet (although I suspect that's not practical in the case of a Mac > Apple TV.
- If you can't connect your Mac to a router/modem via ethernet at Step 1, you could use a Ethernet to Wireless adapter instead. This just means the adapter is connecting to your usual Wi-Fi network and that you're connecting your Mac to the adapter via Ethernet.
- Since you want this to be an *always on* connection, it'd mean your Mac will need to always remain on. It's also why Step 5 above is important. You *may* also need to adjust your System Preferences > Energy Saver settings.

Now, whenever your Mac is connected to the VPN, it will share the connection via Wi-Fi. This means you can connect any device to the new Wi-Fi network you created at Step 13 (such as your Apple TV).

**Using the VPN connection**

To make this work with your Apple TV:

1. On the Mac, click on the new VPN Status icon in the menu bar
2. Select the Connect option pertaining to the VPN connection created previously
3. Once the connection is established, your Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar will change to indicate your Mac is now sharing the VPN via Wi-Fi
4. Now go to your Apple TV and connect it to this Wi-Fi network

Comment: Great! I think I'll use this option, but using a small and cheap router just to connect to the VPN and let the Apple TV connect to the server. The apple configurator app have some vpn options.. would that work?

Comment: I have also read that one should make sure that iPv6 is not used.  How important is that?