# The Apple TV doesn't support native VPN configuration - is there another way to use VPN?

Tags: network, appletv, vpn, dns

**TL;DR:** Apple doesn't allow for native VPN configuration on Apple TVs, is there a reliable way to use a VPN service with my Apple TV?

As someone who lives abroad, a VPN can be a real life saver when it comes to  catching up on shows from home. However, one thing which continues to annoy me is the lack of an option to configure a VPN on an Apple TV. With iOS and macOS, using a VPN is as simple as downloading an app and pressing one button, but this is not the case with the Apple TV.

I understand that some VPN providers offer [smart DNS](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/stream-to-apple-tv-older-gens-with-dns/) solutions, however, the truth is that this is limiting as it fails to provide the same amount of security offered by standard VPNs and completely omits the option to specify a geo-location which would be my primary use for such a service.

As a result, I have been trawling the Internet trying to find a solution. I have come across guides which explain how to put a VPN directly onto a router, however, it is impossible to do so with my router firmware and even if it were, it would come with a few downsides including speed. Other guides suggest using something like a Raspberry Pi to act as a repeater but I do not think this is a reasonable solution for me and it would also prevent my Apple TV from being used as the hub for my HomeKit setup.

Is there a reasonable alternative (software or hardware) for VPN access on AppleTV other than the ones listed above which would solve this issue?

Currently, to circumvent the problem I have been using a VPN on my iPad and then using AirPlay to mirror the video, however, this is rather irritating as it is bottle-necked by Wi-Fi speeds and thus can sometimes buffer and result in low quality.

Comment: @Allan I apologise for the question appearing to be outside of the Help Centre guidelines. In order to prevent this issue from being closed, I have modified it to be pertain more to solving the issue rather than questioning it. Hopefully you approve of these changes. Best

Comment: I have edited your question to leave out the opinion-based part (which cannot be answered here), and emphasize the practical part (i.e. how can I solve my problem).

Comment: @jksoegaard You overlooked the title it seems :)

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to add a "real" native VPN to the AppleTV through software currently. The DNS-based solutions you describe are really not what you would normally expect from a full VPN solution.

The best alternative currently is a hardware solution where you add the VPN externally. I.e. instead of connecting the AppleTV directly to your internet connection, you connect it to a VPN box instead. Such a setup does not prevent your AppleTV from being used as a HomeKit hub.

The VPN box might be a dedicated box that does nothing but encapsulate network traffic from the device into the VPN (could be a specialized off-the-shelf VPN device, or a generic device with VPN software such as a small Linux computer or similar). It might also be just functionality within equipment you already have, such as your existing router or firewall, if they support such VPN functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's a shame that there is no way to add native VPN support on Apple TV. I understand that you have recommended a VPN 'box' solution. As I mentioned in my question, this was something I was hesetant to try; are there any down sides to this solution other than the cost? May it also affect my ATV's ability to act as a hub for my HomeKit setup?

Comment: Well, cost and you have to keep a separate box updated. I cannot see why it would affect your HomeKit setup at all, why do you think that?

Comment: This is the best approach.  There's no reason why have an issue with bandwidth.  HomeKit will still function with a VPN.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348581/will-homekit-remote-access-still-work-if-i-add-a-vpn-to-my-apple-tv/348582#348582

Answer (score 4):

Here is a summary of what did to get my Apple TV to route through a VPN service.

Complete details, including crucial details on how to configure the VPN service (using the System Preferences->Network) are 
[here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285657/how-can-i-set-up-an-apple-tv-4th-gen-connection-to-a-pptp-l2tp-vpn).

1. MacBook Pro running OSX 10.14.3. (Mojave)
2. Wired Ethernet connection from router to the MacBook.
3. VPN service. I used ExpressVPN, although from what I read, several others work as well, and have a similar setup. Follow crucial details 
   on how to configure the VPN [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285657/how-can-i-set-up-an-apple-tv-4th-gen-connection-to-a-pptp-l2tp-vpn).
4. "Internet Sharing" to share internet/VPN service with Apple TV (via local WiFi settings).
5. Connect Apple TV to shared internet connection.